# Check if a popup is tooltip WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF for both ContextMenu and ToolTip popups

```
element is Popup
```

is true 
I need to know if element is ContextMenu or a ToolTip . 
Thanks

Comment: How do you get this `element`?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (element.GetType() == typeof(ContextMenu))
    Console.WriteLine("Context menu!");
else if (element.GetType() == typeof(ToolTip))
    Console.WriteLine("Tool tip!");
```

This gets the type of `element` and writes `Context menu!` if it's a ContextMenu and writes `Tool tip!` if it's a ToolTip.

Comment: Before giving an answer, you should have tried to compile the code you provided first. Correct compilation errors and post working code.
It is also very doubtful (as far as I understand your code) that it will solve the author's problem.
He clearly wrote that his element is Popup.
And it in no way can be cast to the types ContextMenu or ToolTip.

Comment: @EldHasp he said `I need to know if element is ContextMenu or a ToolTip `. "In no way" am I casting to anything. Sure, about the compiler errors, I fixed them with an if-else statement. I hope this is a joke.

Comment: 1) What environment and what type of project are you compiling in?
In Studio 2019 for Project WPF Framework 4.8. such code (even after corrections) will not compiled.
2) TC writes that "element is Popup" returns "true". Therefore, "element.GetType ()" will return either "typeof (Popup)" or a type derived from "Popup". But ContextMenu and ToolTip are not derived from Popup, so the conditions you suggested will NEVER be met.

Without understanding how and / or from where TC gets the "element", it will be impossible to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: You can fix your code (so that it compiles) either by getting and comparing with the type `element.GetType () == typeof (ContextMenu)`. Or, if instead of comparing types, apply a mapping with the type `element is ContextMenu contextMenu`.

Comment: Now, after the new fixes, the code will compiled.
But that will not make it suitable for solving the TC problem.
Since under the condition set by TC "(element is Popup) = true", at best only your last condition from the `else if (element.GetType () = typeof (Popup))` block will be triggered.

Comment: I've answered the question. `I need to know if element is ContextMenu or a ToolTip `

Comment: TC simply does not understand that the problem is not in the type of the element, but in how and where it gets this element from.
Can you imagine a situation in which all the explanations in his question are correct?
Just try to make some test code for yourself to meet the condition "(element is Popup) = true" and so that at least one condition from your code is met.
This is impossible!